# Using Graph API to create an event with map

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, latitude-longitude

I am adding a new event via the graph API.
Is there a secret to making the map appear or does it has to be an official FB place?

This is what i am sending. Everything seems to work (kindof)
A couple of things.
When i view the event, no zip or map are displayed.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated

BTW all the fields are populated and correct

```
       $fb = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'      => FB_APP_ID,
        'secret'     => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'cookie'     => true,
        'fileUpload' => true 
        ));            
        $fb->setAccessToken($_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_ACCESSCODE' ]);

        $data = array(  'access_token' => $_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_ACCESSCODE' ], 
                         'owner'       => $_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_ACCESSCODE' ], 
                         'latitude'    => $event->getLat(),
                         'longitude'   => $event->getLong(),
                         'name'        => $event->getTitle(), 
                         'description' => $description,
                         'start_time'  => date('c', $event->getStart()),
                         'end_time'    => date('c', $event->getEnd()),
                         'street'      => $event->getAddress(),
                         'city'        => $event->getCity(),
                         'state'       => $event->getState(),
                         'zip'         => $event->getZip(),
                         'location'    => $event->getLocation(),
                         'privacy'     => 'OPEN'
                         , basename($fileName) => '@'.$fileName
                         ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the map what you see isn't just an image?

The event documentation says: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ you able to submit the event's profil picture.

Comment: yes but i am talking about the map to the venue.
but it appears that it is working. It just does not show up immediately. So i was doing it correctly, but in test mode i was cancelling the event to early. After about 30 minutes, i went back to the event and the map was there
"Who KNEW!!!"
So this is Answered

Comment: Patience :) yes it is important. :)